# Service calls to database giving duplicate results under load

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, web-services

I'm working with a C# Web API web service that makes a call to a SQL Server 2008  R2 database. Once there, it grabs an ID out of the table (an int) and then marks that ID as "used" (the table has 4 columns - a primary key, the unique id, a bit for used/unused (0 or 1) and the date the unique id was marked as "used"). The ID then gets transported up to the website where it sits in an HTML tag.

Right now, the code first grabs the ID and then marks the ID as used. Under load (beginning at 20 consecutive hits), these consecutive database hits grab IDs before the field can be marked as "used." This means the load grabs multiple IDs at the same time. So we're seeing duplicate IDs in the results when each hit should produce a unique ID that doesn't reappear again. My first thought to mitigate this was simply to reverse the order of operations - mark the ID as used first, which probably won't eliminate the issue, but maybe reduce it.

So the general question is how others deal with database hits under heavy load? The database hits are triggered by home page visits, so the potential for overlap is high (though the website doesn't even approach the traffic that our loads tests are running). I also don't want to initiate any blocking because the website should still function if the IDs don't generate.

Basically, I'm looking to mitigate the service grabbing multiple database records under load. I plan on looking into database locking approaches, but I'm not sure if that will help. Other thoughts?

I haven't posted the actual code since this feels more conceptual, but if posting the code helps, please let me know.

Comment: The way to deal with this is to stop managing IDs manually. It sounds like they are just incrementing values? You should consider using the identity property. It handles these types of concurrency issues with no effort on your part.

Comment: SO really isn't here to help you design your architecture but here are a few ideas.  Why don't you generate your ID in the web service (Guid.NewGuid()) and then pass that to the database?  Or use an identity column in your database so it generates a unique ID when a new row is added to your table.

Comment: Hand off the plucking of your IDs to the database. Could use an `IDENTITY` column, or for a more complex implementation a stored proc that wraps the select and update in a transaction.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your incredible input! I ended up taking this in a different direction by having a controller method generate a new C# GUID, appending the date to it and sending that GUID-date to the webpage. It didn't require a service or a database. So far it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your process is something like this:

1. Web API hit
2. Web API runs a `SELECT` statement for the ID
3. Web API runs an `UPDATE` statement to increment the ID
4. Send back to client

And what's happening is that under load, a second user is getting in between steps 2 & 3.

You need to select and update that ID in a single transaction. You can do this in one of two ways;

1. Wrap it in a transaction, preferably in a Stored Procedure. That SP will `begin` a transaction, select the ID, increment it, then `commit` the transaction and return the ID to the caller.
2. Use the [`OUTPUT` clause in a single `UPDATE` statement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/06/13/output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/) to update & return the new value. Example:

`update SEQUENCETABLE set LASTUSED = lastused+1 output inserted.LASTUSED where SEQUENCE_ID= 'SEQUENCENAME';`